# Use sed to replace ony one occurrence in a certain block

Tags: sed

I want to replace `ignore_broadcast_ssid=1` with `ignore_broadcast_ssid=0`
inside the file `/var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf`.

This would be my first guess:

```
sed 's/ignore_broadcast_ssid=1/ignore_broadcast_ssid=0/g' /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
```

But this replaces this option globally, How can I only replace this in one of the sections, starting with `bss=wlan0-2` inside the file?

```
...

bss=wlan0-2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=0
ssid=temp_wifi
bridge=br-client
bssid=a0:f3:c1:d8:b7:7c

interface=client0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
...
```

Comment: Where are your sections?

Comment: I added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find out the line number of the first text as the starting search index:

```
grep -n "bss=wlan0-2"
```

Let assume it is at Line 10. Then apply your sed command at follow:

```
sed '10s/ignore_broadcast_ssid=1/ignore_broadcast_ssid=0/' /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
```

Make sure you don't have the keyword g at the end of the command as it indicates to replace the matching pattern globally.

Comment: you need `LINE=$(grep -n "bss=wlan0-2" | cut -d':' -f1)` to only get the line

Comment: Great! that works for replacing behind a certain string. And now: [how do you replace the latest occurrence before hitting a certain row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749351/replace-the-latest-occurrence-of-a-string-before-a-certain-row)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/bss=wlan0-2/,/ignore_broadcast_ssid/{s/ignore_broadcast_ssid=1/ignore_broadcast_ssid=0/}' file
```

Comment: This works also, but can you add an explanation and where to find more info?

Comment: This limits `sed`'s  search and replace (`s///`) to lines which contains `bss=wlan0-2` to `ignore_broadcast_ssid`.

Comment: This explains it quite well: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/used.htm - especially the part about "address ranges"