# replace the latest occurrence of a string before a certain row

Tags: awk, replace, sed

I want to replace `ignore_broadcast_ssid=0` with `ignore_broadcast_ssid=1`
inside the file `/var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf`.

This is, how I find out the row number of a string **before** that string:

```
LINE=$(grep -n "bss=wlan0-2" | cut -d':' -f1)
```

And this how to replace **behind** this row:

```
sed $LINE's/ignore_broadcast_ssid=0/ignore_broadcast_ssid=1/g' /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
```

But since the first line of the block is not always `bss=wlan0-2`, how can I only replace inside one of the sections containing `ssid=temp_wifi` inside the same block, but **before** the found string?

```
...

bss=wlan0-2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=0
ssid=temp_wifi
bridge=br-client
bssid=a0:f3:c1:d8:b7:7c

interface=client0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question (the actual problem you're trying to solve is obscured by your question being focused on how to solve the question using the approach you have started with) but it sounds like you just want to replace some text with some other text in a block containing ssid=temp_wifi and that'd just be this:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/ssid=temp_wifi/{sub(/ignore_broadcast_ssid=0/,"whatever")} 1' file
...

bss=wlan0-2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
whatever
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=0
ssid=temp_wifi
bridge=br-client
bssid=a0:f3:c1:d8:b7:7c

interface=client0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ap_isolate=1
disassoc_low_ack=1
preamble=1
wmm_enabled=1
...
```

The above uses the block of text from your question as input.